# Unity 3d C# - Can’t move through the air while jumping

Tags: unity, c#, 3d

The code below allows my character to jump and move which works fine, except I can't move while jumping. I can jump in one place or jump in a certain direction but nothing else. I can't fix it, can someone help?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour {

private CharacterController controller;

public float speed = 1.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 1.0F;
public float gravity = 1.0F;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
void Update() {
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;
        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump")) {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've implemented is called ballistic jumping. It's a perfectly realistic way to handle jumping — after all, in real life we can't change direction in mid-air after jumping — but it turns out to be awful for gameplay. The problem is that, in real life, we can pretty accurately control our direction and speed *before* jumping, and thus land more or less where we want. A game controller or, worse yet, a keyboard doesn't provide such fine motor control, making ballistic jumps really hard to predict and control.

The usual solution is to cheat physics a bit, and allow some degree of steering even while jumping or falling. This turns out to be really intuitive to players, even if they haven't encountered it before (which, of course, is pretty rare nowadays, except for small children): when you notice that your jump isn't going to land where you want, the instinctive impulse is to try and steer in the direction you want to go, even if real-life physics says it should be useless.

Some games go so far as to leave the player with full horizontal movement control while jumping, and letting physics only control the vertical movement. You could implement such jumping e.g. like this (warning: untested code, may contain bugs or typos!):

```
private float verticalVelocity = 0;
void Update() {
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump")) {
            verticalVelocity = jumpSpeed;
        } else {
            verticalVelocity = 0;
        }
    } else {
        verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, verticalVelocity, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed);
    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep jumping mostly ballistic, but allow limited directional control in air:

```
private Vector3 jumpVelocity = Vector3.zero;
void Update() {
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        moveDirection *= groundSpeed;
        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump")) {
            jumpVelocity = moveDirection;
            jumpVelocity.y = jumpSpeed;
        } else {
            jumpVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        }
    } else {
        moveDirection *= midairSpeed;
        jumpVelocity.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    controller.Move((moveDirection + jumpVelocity) * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your horizontal movement is managed inside the controller.isGrounded block.
to handle horizontal movements when jumping you should remove that block from there and for the sake of better air movements, i've added an air friction parameter so the player movements are slower while in air. Also put the CharacterController reference in the start, because GetComponent() shouldn't be used in Update():

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour {

private CharacterController controller;

public float speed = 1.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 1.0F;
public float gravity = 1.0F;
public float airFriction = 0.5f;

private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

void Start(){
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update() {
    moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    moveDirection *= speed;
    if (controller.isGrounded) { 
        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump")) {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
    } else {
        moveDirection *= airFriction;
    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code works but now my character jumps straight up (teleports almost) then floats back down. My Speed is 6, jump speed is 8 and my gravity is 20.

Comment: my bad, it is because the Y value gets set to 0 in the next frame. a workaround would be:
`void Update() {
...
    moveDirection.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    moveDirection.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
...
}
`
rather than setting it to a New Vector3() each frame.

Comment: Now my character can't move.

Comment: @pixelator Poor character...